# Laravel previous page content loading issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a website in Laravel 5, It has a Jobs page where data loaded through ajax which have many filters. When I open a link and come back to the previous page (Jobs page) by clicking the browser back button, it showing me Json data on the browser window instead of loading the whole page.

[image]

Kindly let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please share some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What code should I share?

Comment: I think the controller code which fires after hitting the specific URL would be a good start. And as you pull the data with Javascript please post your blade file and the JS too.

Comment: If you want i can share the link to you

Comment: I don't want a link. You have to share the code inside your question! Otherwise nobody will be able to help you. Also share your routes (according to Ross Wilson's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the same url for the JSON request as you are for the html request then the browser will simply be returning the last response to that url which will be the JSON data.

There are a few different ways to overcome this but essentially you'll have to modify your url so that the browser treats them as different responses.

One way would be to append a query string value to the ajax call e.g. `?json`.

A slightly more complex yet more flexible approach would be to create separate controllers for your views and JSON data and then prefix your JSON routes with something like `/api` e.g.

For the view

**example.com/jobs**  -> `Pages/JobsController@index`

For the json data

**example.com/api/jobs**  -> `Api/JobsController@index`

Comment: Yes, the URL is the same for the JSON request, so should I add json query to the URL or should I send the request to the different URL?

Comment: @AmitKumar Either option should be fine. I'd say if you're planning for your app to grow over time then go for the different url option (e.g. `/api`) but if there are only a few links and/or it'll be easy to maintain/change when you need to then just go for the query string option.

Comment: I created two different url /jobs and /api/job for json, As i said it is using filters so query (parameters) added to current url, if i do not add parameters to the url it working fine, if i add parameters to url it showing me json data.

Comment: @AmitKumar In that case can you give examples of the urls that you're using (both for the page and the ajax call) as well as show the code that's making the ajax call? Also, can you check your network tab in the browser to make sure the call is going to `/ajax` and it's not using a cached version of your js code.

Comment: @AmitKumar Glad I could help!