# Laravel: Why json is displaying on webpage after pressing ctrl+shift+t?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am working on ecommerce site and it is in laravel5.6 framework. My all filters are based on ajax and all filters are working fine. Now my problem suppose i click on color filter my ajax runs and all filters are loaded according to color. After filtering i pressed ctr+w for closing tab and after that i again press the ctr+shift+t and its shwoing json data. I am not sure what is wrong. Here is my code below:-

```
if($request->ajax()){
    // if i click on color filter this condition would run
     return response()->json([
            'view' => (String)View::make('layouts.frontLayout.product-listing')->with(compact('getproducts')),
            'countproducts' => count($getproducts)
      ]);
}else{
      // this condtion would rum when you refersh the page
      return view('front.listings.listing')->with(compact('catdetails','getproducts','title'));
}
```

Here is my blade file :-

```
<div class="category-item" id="appnedProductListing">
    @include('layouts.frontLayout.product-listing')
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code :-

```
$.ajax({
        url : newurl,
        type : 'get',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(resp){
            $("#appnedProductListing").html(resp.view);
            $("#UpdateProCount").text(resp.countproducts+ " styles");
            $(".ListingLoader").hide();
        },
        error:function(){}
    });
```

My products are loaded fine. Only issue is when i pressed the ctrl+w and after that again reopen the tab using ctrl+shif+t its showing json data and if referesh the page its started working normally.
[image]

Now see in above image i have selected the color its working fine.... Now i pressed ctrl+w and aftre that ctrl+shift+t and see the output :-
[image]

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353527/laravel-previous-page-content-loading-issue/53353791#53353791

Comment: @RossWilson thanks its working fine